# Классификация уравнений, графиков и выражений на python

Tags: python-3.x, нейронные-сети, классификация

Есть ввод, например:

```
2x+4=7
y=x^2+4
2+4
и т.д.
```

Необходимо классифицировать этот ввод по категориям (тут уравнение, график и выражение). Всё это нужно сделать на Pyton 3.5. Хочу использовать нейронные сети. Какие инструменты можете посоветовать? Есть ли уже что-то готовое (Чтобы не изобретать велосипед)?
P.S В нейронных сетях опыта пока нет

Comment: Какой формат ввода - ascii, как в вашем примере или всё-же TeX, PDF, скан, фотография или что-то ещё?

Comment: Текст, обычный текст

Comment: Тогда непонятно причем тут нейронные сети. Если в строке не содержится символ "=", то это выражение. Если содержится "y", то это график. Если не то и не другое, то уравнение одной переменной